# How do I display an alert window using a rule in Outlook when I receive a reply to a Flagged Email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, notifications, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have learned to flag emails in Outlook, to keep track of the important ones.

When I receive a reply to one of these emails, it would be nice if a rule would display an alert on my screen, so that I'm made aware of important replies when someone on the flagged email replies.

Is there a way to write a rule so that an alert box is displayed when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot set rules for the recipient's reply to the original flagged message. The reason is that the original flag will not be displayed in the email replied by the recipient, so we have no specific conditions to create rules for it.

Comment: Outlook is a dumb piece of software.

Comment: In order to check your flagged emails more easily, it is recommended that you open the Coversassion view via View>Message group>select Show as Conversations, which is very convenient to view the entire conversation between you and the recipient.